# Limiting Admin Choices Using limit_choices_to

Tags: python, django

I would like to limit the choices for a ForeignKey in the admin UI using limit_choices_to; however, I would like to achieve this without changing the model, since the model is brought in from a library, that I don't have control over. What is the way of dynamically achieving this? Or could I use a field on the admin model to be able to achieve this?

Thanks,
--Eytan

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Django provides an admin hook to modify a foreign keys queryset: [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "car":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Yuji! This helped me achieve what i was looking for. I guess the proper way of doing would be through customizing the ModelForm for the ModelAdmin, but this definitely is easier :)

Comment: @daniyalzade no problem! This _is_ the proper way, or why else is it in the django admin documentation? Overriding the `form` attribute should be done when the django supplied methods are not enough : ) My 2 cents.